# setLightLevel property not working correctly

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I recently started making a mod, and I'm trying to figure out the properties. All of them I am able to get working except the .setLightLevel. I have looked at other posts on here and followed what they state to change, and it's still not registering. Any help?

```
public static void registerBlocks(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event)
                {
                    blocklist.blue_lantern_block = new Block(Block.Properties
                            .create(Material.GLASS)
                            .setLightLevel(1.0F)
                            .hardnessAndResistance(3.5f,3.5f)
                            .sound(SoundType.GLASS))
                            .setRegistryName(location("blue_lantern_block"));
                    
                    logger.info("Blocks registered.");
                }
```